# How to find and replace strings within a *.txt file with Unicode encoding using Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am trying to replace "FullName" with a user input string within all *.txt files in the same folder. The *.txt files seem to be Unicode (shown Unicode when I click File -> Save as).

Every time I run the code it'd replace the "FullName" with some incorrect symbols (e.g. lots of ਍ഀ਍ഀ, and ਍ഀ਍䘀甀氀氀一愀洀攀ഀ਍䨀漀戀倀漀猀椀琀椀漀渀ഀ਍䐀㨀ꀀ㌀ꀀ㠀㠀).

When I made a random *.txt file and saved it as ANSI or saved any of the original file as ANSI, the replacement worked just fine.

Can somebody please help me understand what went wrong here?

```
fullName = input('Full Name: ')
import glob

fullName = input('Full Name: ')
for f in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(f, 'r') as inputfile:
        newText = inputfile.read().replace('FullName', fullName)
    with open(f, 'w') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(newText)
```

Unicode Encoding:

[image: Unicode Encoding]

Aftermaths of replacement:

[image: Aftermaths of replacement]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take our [tour], it only takes a minute. Then, if you have more time check our [help] for better understanding of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows saves Unicode in UTF-16 by default, so try opening the file with `encoding='utf-16'`:

```
for f in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as inputfile:
        newText = inputfile.read().replace('FullName', fullName)
    with open(f, 'w', encoding='utf-16') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(newText)
```

Comment: This will perform badly if the file is big. A better approach in terms of memory would be to read and write a line at a time.

Comment: I was just pointing out the key cause of the OP's issue, but yes, the OP should avoid unnecessarily reading into memory the entire file for better memory efficiency.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. 

Also thanks for pointing out the better approach. In my case the files are simply email signature so the file size is always small. 

Really appreciate the help!